# Maya Python call modul class functions

Tags: python, class, maya

Hey I want to understand the process of importing and reloading scripts with Python in Maya.

I have the following code that throws following error:

```
# NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined #
```

It creates the window but when I press the button it gives me the error above. Would be great if someone could help me what I am missing here.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

class MyClass():

    @classmethod
    def createWindow(cls):

        windowID = 'window'

        if cmds.window(windowID, exists = True):
             cmds.deleteUI('window')

        window = cmds.window(windowID, title="Blast", iconName='Blast', widthHeight=(400, 200) )
        cmds.frameLayout( label='')

        cmds.button( label='Playblast' ,command= 'MyClass.createPlayblast()')

        cmds.showWindow( window )

    @classmethod
    def createPlayblast(cls):

        cmds.playblast( f= "playblast", fmt= "image")
        print "hallo"

MyClass.createWindow()
```

I am calling my modul like this:

```
# call loadTest

import sys
Dir = 'S:/people/Jan-Philipp/python_scripts'
if Dir not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(Dir)
try: reload(loadTest)
except: from loadTest import MyClass

loadTest.MyClass()
```

Cheers, hope you all have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to remove `MyClass.createWindow()` from the window, and leave that to the calling code. As written it will create a window every time you *import* the module.  It's better to put only initialization code into the module scope.

The problem in this case is that you're trying to call the class as if it were a function. If you only want classmethod, you'd do it like this

```
import loadTest

loadTest.MyClass.createWindow()
```

In Python we generally don't need to do make classes which only have class methods:  A module is usually what you'd use. In this case:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

def createWindow():

    windowID = 'window'

    if cmds.window(windowID, exists = True):
         cmds.deleteUI('window')

    window = cmds.window(windowID, title="Blast", iconName='Blast', widthHeight=(400, 200) )
    cmds.frameLayout( label='')

    cmds.button( label='Playblast' ,command= createPlayblast)

    cmds.showWindow( window )

def createPlayblast():

    cmds.playblast( f= "playblast", fmt= "image")
    print "hallo"
```

and

```
import loadTest
loadTest.createWindow()
```

A module is a better tool for grouping related functions than a class.  Classes only make sense in Python if the class contains some persistent data.

Comment: Isent this line in your post wrong in this case? 

cmds.button( label='Playblast' ,command= 'MyClass.createPlayblast()')

would be something like: or?
cmds.button( label='Playblast' ,command= 'createPlayblast()')

Comment: Also, don't use the string-reference version of the callbacks -- pass the python functions directly.  The string versions work differently in the listener and in production code so they produce a lot of bugs.  See https://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet

Comment: Thanks Theodox. Your page and your knowledge are goldmines. Keep up the good work!